# Show text after button press and payment

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an app in which I need a feature that enables the user to see a line or two of text with the remaining part blurred out, and has a button to go to the payments page. After the payment has been done, the blurred out part of the text should become visible. Can someone help me with the same?
I read that I can blur the text using the `ImageFiltered` class, but how do I implement the payment button and the visibility of the text...

Comment: Why don't you just hide the text with a paid flag false, and unhide it with paid flag true?

Answer (score -1):

Use BackdropFilter. Regarding visibility, my idea was just to use the visibility widget with a state change.

```dart
 Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('0' * 10000),
          Center(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: true, //!!!
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: 5.0,
                  sigmaY: 5.0,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  width:`enter code here` 200.0,
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: const Text('Hello World'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

[image: Visible is true]

---

```dart
 Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('0' * 10000),
          Center(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: false, //!!!
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: 5.0,
                  sigmaY: 5.0,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: const Text('Hello World'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

[image: Visible is false]